# DATEDIFF() refuses to run on a MySQL Event

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql5

I want to create an event that will run every day and see if an account soon expires. The `soon_expires` cell will be later used by a Bash script that sends an e-mail to related user informing him of the situation.

This is the content of my event (using phpmyadmin):

```
SELECT * FROM users;

IF DATEDIFF(expirationtime, CURDATE()) < 45 THEN
    SET soon_expires = 1; 
ELSE 
    SET soon_expires = 0; 
END IF;
```

However, it returns an error, saying

```
#1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF DATEDIFF(expirationtime, CURDATE()) < 45 THEN SET soon_expires = 1; EL' at line 3
```

I also tried to create a trigger, which worked as intended. But I realized that a trigger will run only when the row updates - `expirationtime` is more or less static, so a trigger will not suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT check_expire
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2019-08-21'
DO
UPDATE users
SET soon_expires = (DATEDIFF(expirationtime, CURRENT_DATE) < 45);
```

or

```
UPDATE users
SET soon_expires = 1
WHERE DATEDIFF(expirationtime, CURRENT_DATE) < 45;
```

First variant updates all records in the table, second one updates only those records which will be expired within 45 days.

Comment: Thanks. I used the second variant. If I want to do the "reverse" (set to 0 if date further than 45 days) should I make a separate event? I tried just copying the last two lines (just changing 1 to 0 and < to >), but it returned a syntax error.

Comment: *If I want to do the "reverse" (set to 0 if date further than 45 days) should I make a separate event?* 1st variant will both set to 1 if <45 and set to 0 if >=45. So use this variant and do not create additional event. But you may, of course, if you want... *it returned a syntax error.* Be more careful...